# kubectl get nodes unable to connect to the server on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubectl

I have deployed kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Nodes, one master node and one worker node. Its a free tier t2.micro machine with 1 CPU.

I installed and configured everything and on day 1 everything works fine. `kubectl get nodes` command was responding without any delay and i was able to create MYSQL deployment.

Next day when i tried `kubectl get nodes` i was getting **The connection to the server :6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?** and even sometimes i am getting **Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout**

I checked the following things to verify whether kubernetes is working or not
`sudo systemctl status kubelet` it was in active status

Even its surprising that sometime `kubectl get nodes`  works perfectly and sometime it return **The connection to the server :6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?**

I am not able to understand how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Have you considered switching to [managed node groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html)? Is the instance deployed in the correct subnet? From your master node, is the worker node pingable? Have you checked the ACLs and Security Groups?

Comment: As of now i want to try on EC2 nodes only

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a mismatch between the actual master node IP (`apiserver`) and the `server` entry configured in your `~/.kube/config`. Verify that they both match and if not, just update the `server` entry.

Keep in mind that EC2 instances can and will fail (I've seen them randomly crashing even on managed clusters). This could explain why one day your control plane was accessible on one IP and no longer accessible on the next day.

Comment: master node IP (private IP) is matching the server entry in ~/.kube/config. I have observed that kube-apiserver container is getting frequently killed and new container getting started, will this create problem

Comment: Do a desc on the apiserver, check the Last State and Reason and the resource Requests allocated. It could be running out of memory and getting OOMKilled.

Comment: @kuldeep ,  Have you been checking solution offered by @davidmontoyago?

Comment: I created cluster on t2.medium instance and now its working as expected, i think issue was due to memor